# How to list all git tags associated with a specific version of a file

Tags: git, github, tags

Given a git repo with multiple tags sprinkled throughout the history, and a specific file that changes infrequently, how do I list all of the tags associated with each version of the file?  (By version, I mean file contents or blob.)

I'm accustomed to using `git log --color --decorate --oneline --graph` to look at the history, and I can look at that for a given file, seeing all of the commits that introduced changes; however, all of the tags that applied to intermediate commits are not shown, even though checking out any of those tags would produce the same version of the file of interest.

How would I include the intermediate git tags on the abbreviated log history lines?  (GitHub has a similar way of listing all of the tags on a commit that include the same changes.  Essentially, I want to verify that behavior with `git log` or similar.)

Comment: The connection from tag to commit is the same as the connection from branch-name to commit: one name stores one hash ID. The main difference between the two is that we *expect* branch names to move, and they *do* move, so we use the branch name as a clue to find all commits from that commit (the branch tip) backwards, while we don't do that for tags. Given that we don't do that for tags, how do you define tags "associated with" a version of a file?

Comment: This definition—whatever it is—will be the key to how to do this. For instance, one way would be to use `git rev-parse <tag>:<path>` for the file path. This spills out the associated blob hash ID, if a file exists at that path in the tagged commit, or an error if not. For each distinct blob hash ID, count the number of tags that turned it up (and/or display them).

Comment: If that's *not* your definition, choose your definition and go from there.

Comment: Also, if you want both branch names *and* tag names, consider `git log`'s `--simplify-by-decoration` option. I'm not sure if that will play well with whatever your goal is here, though.

Comment: To answer your question about the definition, does this help?  I want all tags for any commits that contain the exact same contents (blob) for a given file.  In other words, I want to know how many tags I can checkout and find the exact same file contents (i.e., "version") for my file of interest.

Comment: OK, so if you just want the *count* (for *all* tags), use `git for-each-ref refs/tags` to iterate over all tag names (you'll probably want `--format` to limit the output a bit). Read these tag names, one at a time, and try to `git rev-parse` the given tag/path pair. If that works, you get a blob hash ID, if not, you get an error (so discard the tag). If you get a blob hash ID, count the tag as going with that version of the file.